# RegEx, matching if not containing

Tags: regex

I've been trying to figure out how to write this regular expression. It is to be used for ISAPI_Rewrite, a module for IIS 6, for doing URL rewriting.

I want the url `/hg/<parameter>` to be mathed, so it can be rewrited to `/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/<parameter>`.

I've matched it using `^/hg/(.*)`.

My problem is, if the URL `/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/<parameter>` is used, the regex should NOT match. Using the above regex with this URL, will rewrite to `/hg/hgwebdig.cgi/hgwebdig.cgi/<parameter>` which is not correct.

Can you help me create the matching pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#rxLookAhead) to do this:

```
"^/hg/(?!hgwebdir.cgi)(.*)"
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is a great tutorial for regular expressions. =)

Comment: When looking up syntax for regexps, though, be sure to get your information for the correct regexp dialect! There are regexps in perl, java, .NET and many other languages/programs, and there are many small but significant differences. For example, the last time I needed a negative lookahead it was in vim, and the expression looked a lot different from what Jens wrote here.

Comment: @Carl: The site I linked covers some of the quirks of different regex implementations. Not vim, though =)

Comment: To be sure, I wasn't contradicting you! I was just slapping an obligatory "here be dragons" sticker on the topic. I've occasionally been bitten by using the regexp syntax I'd learned from a different environment than the target, and wanted to save Tommy that same pain.

Comment: @Carl, good point. I had guessed that the rewrite module in question wouldn't support look-arounds. But after looking it up, I saw it did support look-aheads (not look-behind), so I added the link to Jens' answer.